# How to extract a value from an xml object?

Tags: php, xml, printing, display, serialization

I am trying to print a value from this XML ($xml), I tried every single way to do it but nothing.

I am using ASMX Web services so i had to parse the object response to XML and i used XMLSerializer to do it.

I just want to know what i am doing wrong to print a single value from entire XML.

**Here is my code:**

```
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
require_once 'xmlserializer/XML/Serializer.php';
$client = new SoapClient('https://omegasandbox.megasys.net:444/Client/WebServices/CustomerPortal.asmx?WSDL');
$token = $client->Login(array('clientNumber' => 'xxx', 'userName' => 'xxxxxx', 'password' => 'xxxxxxx'));

echo '<br><br>';

$realtoken = $token->LoginResult;
$summary = $client->GetAccountSummary(array('token'=>$realtoken, 'accountNumber' => 1111));
$summary = json_encode($summary);
$data = json_decode($summary, true);

// An array of serializer options.
$serializer_options = array (
  'addDecl' => TRUE,
  'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
  'indent' => '  ',
  'rootName' => 'json',
  'mode' => 'simplexml'
); 

$Serializer = &new XML_Serializer($serializer_options);
$status = $Serializer->serialize($data);

if (PEAR::isError($status)) {
  die($status->getMessage());
}

$xml = $Serializer->getSerializedData();

echo "echo xml <br><br>";
echo $xml; 
echo "<br><br>";
echo "echo xml2<br><br>";
echo $xml2 =  htmlspecialchars_decode($xml);
```

Hope you can help me, thank you.

---

**EDIT:**

Finally I figure it out the final step. Here is the final code:

```
<?php 
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
require_once 'xmlserializer/XML/Serializer.php';
$client = new SoapClient('https://omegasandbox.megasys.net:444/Client/WebServices/CustomerPortal.asmx?WSDL');
$token = $client->Login(array('clientNumber' => 'xxx', 'userName' => 'xxxxx', 'password' => 'xxxxxx'));

echo '<br><br>';

$realtoken = $token->LoginResult;
$summary = $client->GetAccountSummary(array('token'=>$realtoken, 'accountNumber' => 11111));
$summary = json_encode($summary);
$data = json_decode($summary, true);

// An array of serializer options.
$serializer_options = array (
  'addDecl' => TRUE,
  'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
  'indent' => '  ',
  'rootName' => 'json',
  'mode' => 'simplexml'
); 

$Serializer = &new XML_Serializer($serializer_options);
$status = $Serializer->serialize($data);

if (PEAR::isError($status)) {
  die($status->getMessage());
}

$xml = $Serializer->getSerializedData();

ob_start();
echo $xml;
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$order = simplexml_load_string(htmlspecialchars_decode($data));

//This was the final step.
echo $order->GetAccountSummaryResult[0]->any[0]->GetAccountSummary[0]->LoanAmount;
?>
```

Thanks to @Rasclatt for the big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the results of `$xml` is in a string form (although, it's probably coming from a `__toString()` method and not really a string, so this method may not work without outputting the string to a output buffer first (which is, I'm sure, not what the class is intending) but you could use `simplexml_load_string()` at that point:

```
print_r(simplexml_load_string($xml));
```

Just a portion of your image:

```
$xml = '<GetAccountSummary xmlns="">
    <OpenDate>02/19/2016</OpenDate>
    <LoanAmount>$15,000.00</LoanAmount>
    <Tenn>48</Tenn>
    <Frequency>Monthly</Frequency>
    <Rate>23. 9900 %</Rate>
    <PaymentAmount>$488.94</PaymentAmount>
    <NextDueDate>03/19/2016</NextDueDate>
    <NextAmountDue>$488.94</NextAmountDue>
    <CurrentBalance>$15,000.00</CurrentBalance>
    <UnpaidLateFees>$0.00</UnpaidLateFees>
    <UnpaidOtherFees>$0.00</UnpaidOtherFees>
</GetAccountSummary>';

print_r(simplexml_load_string($xml));
```

**Gives you:**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [OpenDate] => 02/19/2016
    [LoanAmount] => $15,000.00
    [Tenn] => 48
    [Frequency] => Monthly
    [Rate] => 23. 9900 %
    [PaymentAmount] => $488.94
    [NextDueDate] => 03/19/2016
    [NextAmountDue] => $488.94
    [CurrentBalance] => $15,000.00
    [UnpaidLateFees] => $0.00
    [UnpaidOtherFees] => $0.00
)
```

I am sure the `XML_Serializer` class has an `xml->array` and/or `xml->object` so you will want that to locate that method in that class file(s).

---

**EDIT**
I noticed you are echoing browser-safe markup to your page, you need to decode it back with `htmlspecialchars_decode()`:

```
$xml = $Serializer->getSerializedData();
ob_start();
echo $xml;
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$order = simplexml_load_string(htmlspecialchars_decode($data));
echo $order->OpenDate;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I already did that method but it is the same thing, and about 

print_r(simplexml_load_string($xml));

It doesnt display the object like that. 

This is how the object displays:

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [GetAccountSummaryResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [any] => 02/19/2016$15,000.0048Monthly23.9900 %$488.9403/19/2016$488.94$15,000.00$0.00$0.00$0.00$15,000.00$0.00$15,098.60AActive$98.60$0.00$0.002013 Ford Fusion2013FordFusion ) )

Comment: I think this is all about that there are an object inside of another object, but how can i display a value from there?

Comment: Can you paste that xml instead of an image of it?

Comment: Also have you tried doing a buffered option? `ob_start(); $xml = $Serializer->getSerializedData(); echo $xml; $data = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); print_r(simplexml_load_string($data));`

Comment: I would also look at the documentation for the `SimpleXMLElement` class, that may help since it appears that the element is already that kind of object.

Comment: XML  PART 1(Too long) : 

<GetAccountSummary xmlns=""><OpenDate>02/19/2016</OpenDate><LoanAmount>$15,000.00</LoanAmount><Term>48</Term><Frequency>Monthly</Frequency><Rate>23.9900 %</Rate><PaymentAmount>$488.94</PaymentAmount><LastPaidDate/><NextDueDate>03/19/2016</NextDueDate><NextAmountDue>$488.94</NextAmountDue><CurrentBalance>$15,000.00</CurrentBalance><UnpaidLateFees>$0.00</UnpaidLateFees><UnpaidOtherFees>$0.00</UnpaidOtherFees><PaymentOverShortAmount>$0.00</PaymentOverShortAmount><TotalBalance>$15,000.00</TotalBalance><PastDueAmount>$0.00</PastDueAmount>

Comment: XML PART 2:

<PayoffAmount>$15,098.60</PayoffAmount><AdminStatus>A</AdminStatus><InternalStatus>Active</InternalStatus><IBUnpaidInterest>$98.60</IBUnpaidInterest><IBYTDInterestPaid>$0.00</IBYTDInterestPaid><IBTotalInterestPaid>$0.00</IBTotalInterestPaid><LastPaymentAmount/><LastPaymentPrincipalPaid/><LastPaymentInterestPaid/><LastPaymentOtherBalancePaid/><LastPaymentEnterDate/><LastPaymentPreviousBalance/><CollateralDescription>2013 Ford Fusion</CollateralDescription><CollateralVehicleYear>2013</CollateralVehicleYear><CollateralVehicleMake>Ford</CollateralVehicleMake>

Comment: XML PART 3: 
<CollateralVehicleModel>Fusion</CollateralVehicleModel></GetAccountSummary>

Comment: I Tried that buffered option, but it seems doesnt have anything on ob_get_contents() method in parameters, so it doesnt display anything, so i put there the $xml var but it doesnt displayed nothing either.

Comment: So u say that the problem is that the XML is not a string at all?

Comment: Well, when you sent this: `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [GetAccountSummaryResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [any] => 02/19/2016$15,000.0048Monthly23.9900 %$488.9403/19/2016$488.94$15,000.00$0.00$0.00$0.00$15,000.00$0.00$15,098.60AActi‌​ve$98.60$0.00$0.002013 Ford Fusion2013FordFusion ) )` there are two `SimpleXMLElement` so I think it's already using `SimpleXMLElement`. When you `echo` it might be using `SimpleXMLElement()->__toString()` to generate the xml string.

Comment: As for my buffer option, did you copy exactly?

Comment: I just copied and pasted all the stuff you posted in the comments, and the xml has a bunch of hidden characters, like tabs or something so it's all malformed when it goes to convert it. Once I removed the oddities, it all parsed correctly.

Comment: Oh i did not know that,  so when you do an echo it automatically parse to string? ,

Yes i copied exactly

ob_start(); $xml = $Serializer->getSerializedData(); echo $xml; $data = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); print_r(simplexml_load_string($data));

Comment: Yea look at `<LastPaymentAmount />`. Between `<` and `Last..` there are two hidden characters that make the tag invalid

Comment: I just found it because it was giving me errors, and as I went down the xml tags, my application highlight open and close tags and when I went into an open tag, the close tag didn't highlight meaning it was not the same, even though it appeared the same.

Comment: No your's is good, darn, I was hoping that was it. It was probably SO that malformed it in the comment. Here is what I submitted above:

Comment: O stupid me, you are echoing a browser safe version of the xml. You need to echo `htmlspecialchars_decode($xml);`

Comment: i did an echo of  that decoding  and now it displays this:

02/19/2016$15,000.0048Monthly23.9900 %$488.9403/19/2016$488.94$15,000.00$0.00$0.00$0.00$15,000.00$0.00$15,098.60AActive$98.60$0.00$0.002013 Ford Fusion2013FordFusion string(1306) " 02/19/2016$15,000.0048Monthly23.9900 %$488.9403/19/2016$488.94$15,000.00$0.00$0.00$0.00$15,000.00$0.00$15,098.60AActive$98.60$0.00$0.002013 Ford Fusion2013FordFusion "

Comment: Well now displays just the object that i need i guess

Comment: But now how can i get those values

Comment: Edit your original post with what you have now. I can show you. I am not sure what you are working with.

Comment: Do you get an xml string from that?

Comment: No, i am just echoing the htmldecoding version of $xml ,  look my results page i added something

Comment: htmldecoding only removes </> and variable names,   im kinda new in this thing, so i dont know many functions yet.

Comment: What you are doing when you use that function is converting browser-safe html to real html. If you look at your browser source you will see the xml is there as valid markup

Comment: do the same buffer code around `$xml2 =  htmlspecialchars_decode($xml); echo htmlspecialchars_decode($xml);`, that should produce the object you want after you parse it.

Comment: Yeah that worked like a charm,  now i have to print a value from it, but it supposed that i used serializer to parse an object to xml, now i have to use serializer again?

Comment: i mean a XML not XML Object

Comment: To print a value from it you assign it to an object: `$order = simplexml_load_string(htmlspecialchars_decode($data)); echo $order->OpenDate;`

Comment: That doesnt display it

Comment: It doesnt display the value

Comment: What the heck!! I would have to have access to it to troubleshoot then because that should have worked!

Comment: Darn i cant give you the access this is a company project so if i do that they kill me haha 
And yeah its weird that should have worked, i only have 1 manual with a few pages to how to use this API  (15 pages...) and it uses .NET but i am parsing everything to PHP and there is no documentation or information of people having issues or anything about it, so i am alone in this haha well not now u are helping me and i apreciatte it for real.

Comment: Good news buddy, finally i figure it out! 

echo $order->GetAccountSummaryResult[0]->any[0]->GetAccountSummary[0]->LoanAmount;

that was it...

Thanks for everything. Cheers!